# Problem with cin.getline() inside of a loop

Tags: c++

The loop works well as long as it enters less than 10 characters as an option, but if I enter more simply ignore the cin.getline.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    char name[3][11];
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cin.getline(name[i],10,'\n');
    }
    
}
```

i tried with `fflush(stdin)`,`cin.get()`,`cin.ignore` but doesnt work, I want to enter a string of any amount of characters and only take ten.

An example of what I did to try:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    char name[3][11];
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        cin.getline(name[i],10,'\n');
    }
    
}
```

I really read a lot of problems like this, but I cant´t find a solution.

Comment: Guessing is not the developer's way. Have you tried to read `std::istream.getline()` manual? *The `failbit` flag is set if the function extracts no characters, or if the delimiting character is not found once (n-1) characters have already been written to s. Note that if the character that follows those (n-1) characters in the input sequence is precisely the delimiting character, it is also extracted and the `failbit` flag is not set (the extracted sequence was exactly n characters long).*

Comment: @273K but it is supposed to be solved with cin.ignore, right?

Comment: Guessing again? Why don't you read the manual about what does `ignore()`.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is larger than the `char[]` array can hold, `cin.getline()` will set the `failbit` on the `cin` stream. In which case, you would need to call `cin.clear()` to reset the stream's error state before you can continue reading from the stream again.

Since you don't know the size of the user's input ahead of time, you should be using `std::string` instead of `char[]`, as `std::string` can grow in size as input is read into it, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name[3];
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        getline(cin, name[i]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it. It doesn't work for me with `cin.clear`, I've been seeing very similar posts as well as seeing the references. The thing is that afterwards I have to print each character of the name, that's why I used `char` instead of string.

Comment: "*It doesn't work for me with `cin.clear`*" - then you are not using it correctly. "*I have to print each character of the name, that's why I used `char` instead of string*" - you can print a whole `std::string` at a time just as easily as you can print a `char[]`, eg: `cout << name[i];` If you really need to print each character separately, you can loop through the `std::string`, eg: `for(char ch : name[i]) { cout << ch; }`